# How to exclude bounces from users just clicking "Sign In App" to navigate to a subdomain in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain, authentication, bounce

I've got `www.example.com` and `app.example.com`. I control both. On the "www" site, there's a "Sign In" hyperlink that sends people to the app's login page (a known URL on the `app` subdomain).

Some people took the habit of going to "www" and just click on "Sign In" to get to the "app". This results in a lot of quick bounces that I'd like to filter out (or isolate from "normal" traffic)

Can it be done? How could I do this? Any ideas?

**Update 1**

Both `www` and `app` are set up under the same "Analytics property" and I currently have three views:

- App (filters out all `www.example.com` pages)
- Website (filters out all `app.example.com` pages)
- Website + App

[image: Analytics Property Setup]

I can change all that if need be.

**Update 2**

If the user goes **directly** to the app's login page, I don't want to log the session at all (because that user never browsed the www website).

Comment: Good question. I am assuming that app.example.com isn't using the same Analytics property as the www.example.com site?

Comment: How familiar are you with Google Tag Manager? You could trigger a fake pageview whenever someone clicks on the Login link. That might skew your stats, but it would fix the bounce rate.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins, I added more information on the question. I'm not super familiar with neither Analytics or GTM, but I'm usually a pretty smart guy and can read doc ;)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the simplest way to fix this issue is to leave the login URL from the "app" subdomain in the Analytics "Website" view.

Update your view level filter, change it to exclude with the following Regex.

```
^https:\/\/app.example.com+\/(?!login$).*?$
```

Replace app.example.com with your actual app subdomain's hostname, and login with the exact page path (excluding leading forward slash) of your login URL. The crux here is the `?!` which marks a negative.

This will exclude the entire app subdomain, except for the login page. Which will filter out all activity on that subdomain, but remove bounces from your Website view.

Disclaimer: I've not tested this regex in Analytics, but in Regex101 it works fine.

Comment: The regex works in Google Analytics as well, but that solution won't really work because that would also count all users directly going to the app's login page (e.g. never browsing the www site) and would create a bounce from the login page. In the end, that would increase both the session count and bounce rate.

Comment: That's a fair point.